# Unable to get any $_POST data from any form

Tags: codeigniter

I have tried many google hits but I am yet unable to retrieve any POST data from forms, $_POST is just an empty array `array(0) { }`. I found few posts which was saying that problem is in .htaccess which doesn't correctly redirect my POST data but any of those posts didn't help me. I have tried many .htaccess files I found but none of them worked with POST data.

I am using Debian Jessie with Apache 2.4.10, PHP 5.6.14-0+deb8u1. I have `AllowOverride all` inside `<Directory` at my VHOST file. CodeIgniter 3.0.3. I have `var_dump($_POST);` at top of the index.php for testing. I also have enabled `rewrite_module`. There are no errors in the apache2 error.log file.

Here is my setup:

**Controller: Admin.php**

```
<?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

    }

    public function index()
    {

        if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged']))
        {
            $this->load->view('admin/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/default/header');
            $this->load->view('admin_login');
            $this->load->view('templates/default/footer');
        }

    }

    public function login()
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            echo "Validation failed!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Validation success!";
        }


    }
}
```

**View: admin_login.php:**

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/admin/login/">
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Kirjaudu sisään</h2>
<label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Sähköpostiosoite</label>
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Sähköpostiosoite" required autofocus>
<label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Salasana</label>
<input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Salasana" required>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Muista minut
    </label>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Kirjaudu</button>
```

**Current .htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **action is wrong**. It should come like this

```
action="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/login/">
```

as well as load url in helpers

```
$this->load->helper('form','url');
```

---

as well as in these input tags there is **no name attribute**

```
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Sähköpostiosoite" required autofocus>
<input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Salasana" required>
```

---

Do like this

**In controller**

```
$this->load->helper('form'); #load library
```

**In view**

```
<?

$attributes = array('class' => 'form-signin');
echo form_open('admin/login/', $attributes);

$data1 = array(
              'id'                  => 'inputEmail',
              'class'               => 'form-control',
              'Placeholder'         => 'Sähköpostiosoite',
              'name'                => 'email',
            );

echo form_input($data1);

$data2 = array(
              'id'                  => 'inputPassword',
              'class'               => 'form-control',
              'Placeholder'         => 'Salasana',
              'name'                => 'password',
            );

echo form_password($data2);

echo form_submit('submit', 'Log In');
echo form_close();
```

Comment: Thank you! I got the submit button in $_POST and I got it fully working by adding name attributes to your answer. I edited your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
In controller add `$this->load->helper(array('form','url'));` in `function __construct()`

In View:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/login">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Kirjaudu sisään</h2>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Sähköpostiosoite</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Sähköpostiosoite" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Salasana</label>
    <input type="password" name = "password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Salasana" required>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Muista minut
        </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Kirjaudu</button>
```

Hope this help! ^^

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think the error was name attributes which I didn't have so you are also correct. However Abdulla s answer is more of "correct way" to do the forms so I will mark his answer as correct one.